# How to properly say "the email that I've sent you"?

Tags: formality, email, that

What would be the most formal way to say the following:

I wanted to see your thoughts about the email that I sent you last Thursday.

I am a little unsure about "the email that I sent you". I feel there should be a more professional way to say this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it!

PS: Directed to a prospective employer.

Comment: Who is this email to: boss, colleague, friend, relative? That is important information.

Comment: Edit that information into your question (your OP).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this is for a prospective employer.

Comment: The more information you include in your OPs the easier it will be for the community to offer cogent suggestions and answers - you should edit in that information. When you do this I will upvote your OP.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. How do you edit questions?

Comment: Normally we say "hear your thoughts" rather than "see your thoughts".

Comment: look below the tags [formality][email][that] and you will see "edit", after you're done "save edit".

Comment: Thanks just figured it out! Wow, Thank you TRomano, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @TRomano Yes. My mind too was just boggling at the prospect of 'seeing' someone's thoughts!

Comment: Exact311 - when you have a few moments go up to the SE title bar look for "HELP" on the right side, click on it and then take the "TOUR" it will teach what you need to know about this place.

Comment: You're very welcome. Enjoy this site, it's a great place to learn.

Comment: "I look forward to receiving your reply."  I just came across this elsewhere in Stack Exchange.  I love it.  I've used it once already.  I wish I could post it as an Answer, to make it easier for people to find.

Answer (score 1):

An example: **Sir, could you please share your thoughts about the email that I sent you last Thursday? Thank you.**

Comment: This is good. Would there be a way to sound less demanding?

Comment: It doesn't sound demanding to my ears - it sounds open and honest but polite.

Comment: I was thinking maybe, "I wanted to hear your thoughts about the email that I sent you last Thursday." Would this be formal enough?

Comment: Less formal - you asked for "most formal" so I included "Sir", "please" and "thank you" - but what you wrote sounds OK, too. But be polite.

Comment: May I ask you kindly if you could confirm that you received my email of last Thursday, and, if possible, let me have your thoughts about it, please.

Comment: We all have our own ways of doing these things and I suppose yours is as relevant to your neck of the woods as mine is to ours. And especially as I owe you one, I will gladly up vote you.

Comment: Thanks @WS2, but I was "speaking" to Exact311. Don't go contrary on me, now.

Comment: @WS2 - Hey! You! Get offa my cloud! ;-) You oughtta submit that WS2. Maybe Exact'll upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

By asking a prospective employer about his thoughts on an email you sent previously you may appear to be pushy.  It depends on what was in the email.  If the prospective employer asked for your input on something and you are responding, it would be appropriate to ask this.  If instead you are inquiring about your resume or cover letter this may not be approprite.

For the latter it would be better to just send a follow-up note stating your continued interest in the position, referencing the email you sent earlier, and offering to answer any questions he may have.  This way you appear to be the one offering to do something rather than vice versa.

In the two career development courses I've taken it is appropriate to constantly stay in touch with a prospective employer after you've had the first interview or contact.  You may do this via phone calls or emails after a formal written mailed letter thanking for the opportunity and interview. Personal telephone calls are preferred because responses to emails can more easily be avoided by the recipient and a personal telephone call indicates you are blocking time out of your day to make one-on-one contact.

It is also appropriate in business to return telephone messages within twentyfour hours if you reach a voice mail.  You should also prepare a voice mail or administrative assistant resonse before calling  so that you do not appear to be stumbling over your words.  Make sure you are not in a noisy environment like the train station or a bar when calling back and always return calls during business hours; not too early and not too late.  Remember 10:00AM ET USA is the busiest time in the world for teleconference meetings in business so you may want to avoid that.

Sorry if this is way more information than you were asking for.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot Raoul DeChagny. This is definitely good career advice and it is greatly appreciated!